# CakePHP Group get user information

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, oop, cakephp

How can I get the group information about my users..?
In my table users I have a row group_id (id = 1)
This id is linked to my table groups. (id 1 = group admin)

So what I want is when a user logged in example, Welcome User || You are Admin.

I've trying to do this, but it doesn't work. Does anybody know what's wrong?

```
$group = $this->User->Group->findById($id); 

    $users = $this->User->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.group_id' => $id
        )
    ));

    echo $group;
```

Many Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Easy. And it's not even necessary to use the containable behavior, as long as the user group is on the first level of association. It's important that you have all your associations set within your models

```
user.php (Model)
var $belongsTo = array('Group');

group.php (Model)
var $hasMany = array('User');
```

Assuming you know the id of your user all you have to do is this:

```
users_controller.php
$user = $this->User->read(null, $id);
```

This will give you an array from which you can access the associated group like this:

```
$user['Group']['name']; //or whatever key you use for the term "Admin"
```

Answer (score -1):

use the [containable behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable)

It looks like you're trying to find all the users in a group. Turn the query around:

```
$users = $this->User->find('first',array(
    'conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$id),
    'contain'=>array('Group')
));
```

collect your data from $users['Group']

Comment: Hi this does not work.. I use cake php 1.3.. I would like to see under wich group a user is logged on.

Comment: I've changed the group and user around. if you have the user id, plug it in and you'll see all the associated groups